# Line integral over multiple lines by parameterizing the curves

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, parametric, line-integrals

[image]

I have solved this problem by setting a relationship between x and y for the 2 lines and got 11. However, when I try solving by the method of parameterization, I come up with 36.

I tried setting $C_1 = <5t,t>$ and $C_2=<5+t,1-t>$

Then for $C_1$, $dx = 5dt$ and $dy = dt$. For $C_2$, $dx=dt$ and $dy=-dt$

Plugging these values into the integrals I have:
[image]

which add to 36. I can't find my mistake.

Thank you!

Comment: Your parameteization of $C_2$ is wrong. Did you try checking what the end points were?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry, that wasn't my parameterization. The one I actually used to get what in the problem is 5+t, 1-t

Comment: Oh I see, your second integral was entered incorrectly. It should be $(5+t)^2$, not $(5+t^2)$